# Why can't the Edge browser expand the 'window' object in the DevTools console tab?

Tags: javascript, browser, microsoft-edge

When I input `window` in Edge Console Tab, and click the expand arrow, got nothing.

```bash
> window  // click to expand, but got nothing
```

Here is the Edge expand result.Please click to view

[image: 1]

But it well in Chrome or Firefox.
Why?

[Here is the Chrome expand result.Please click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiJqD.png)

Comment: because Microsoft take the Chrome pig, slap their lipstick on it, and pretend it's something that isn't the Chrome pig :p - probably a bug in Edge - or perhaps it's a "feature"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested and can reproduce the issue in Edge Stable. I also tested in [Edge Canary](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/canary) and found that `window` in console can expand well. That means the issue has been fixed in future version of Edge. We can wait for the new version of Edge Stable to release.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this also occurs in Brave so it might be a chromium issue (pure speculation there).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).